# check for null variables

Tags: c#

I have multiple variables which I set prior to creating an object, I want to check if any of those variables in null, if any variable then display an error. Is there a way to incorporate this in a foreach loop?

For eg.

```
Var Var1 = blah1;
Var Var2 = blah2;
Var Var3 = blah3;
Var Var4 = blah4;
Var Var5 = blah5;

foreach(var above, if any is null)
Errmessage
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `foreach` requires that they be in an `IEnumerable`. If you specifically want `foreach`, you'll need to put each of those into a collection.

Comment: Are you looking to check **ALL** variables in the local function or only a subset?

Comment: @p.campbell actually to be precise foreach needs an IEnumerable

Comment: Wait a minute, you just said that *you* set them. If you set them to bad values then don't report an error; *fix the bug* so that you are not setting them to bad values anymore.

Comment: @PreetSangha: To be precise foreach needs *an implementation of the foreach pattern*. It need not be an implementation of IEnumerable.

Comment: @EricLippert - LOL - I stand humbled. Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I, personally, would have separate checks for each variable.  On "error message" for multiple validation checks is a bad idea.

The main reason for this is that your "error message" should likely be an [`ArgumentNullException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8a0dfcy.aspx), which should provide the proper parameter name.  This will be different per variable.  Even if you use a custom exception, providing information about *which* variable was improperly specified is worth the extra coding effort.

That being said, if you want to do this, you can use:

```
var Var1 = blah1;
var Var2 = blah2;
var Var3 = blah3;
var Var4 = blah4;
var Var5 = blah5;

if ( (new object[] {Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5}).Any(v => v==null))
    throw new Exception("Your error here");
```

Comment: I agree, seperate checks are better. If I nest all the variables in one If statement, is there a way to know which variable was null? e.g. if(var1 != null && var2 != null && var3 != null)

Comment: @user793468 No, not directly.  It's part of the problem here.  If you are just trying to shorten the code, you could use something like CuttingEdge.Conditions: http://conditions.codeplex.com/  It'd let you write the checks as one line per variable, and still provide relatively meaningful exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

Put them in an IEnumerable such as an array

```
foreach(var v in new object[] { var1, var2, .... }){
 if(v == null) {
   Errmessage...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put them into a list of `object` and loop over it:

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();
list.add(Var1);
list.add(Var2);
// etc.

foreach(object obj in list)
{
    if(obj == null) //message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My first inclination would be not to use separate variables but instead one Dictionary:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

dict["var1"] = blah1;
// etc.

foreach(var value in dict.Values)
{
    if(value == null)
        throw new Exception(errorMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to track them in a list to the side and then loop through the list:

```
List<object> objects = new ....;

Var Var1 = blah1;  objects.add(Var1)...
Var Var2 = blah2;  ...
Var Var3 = blah3;  ...
Var Var4 = blah4;  ...
Var Var5 = blah5;  ...

foreach(var objRef, in objects)
    if( objRef == null )
       Errmessage; break ?
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of your variables may change in the future and you don't want to manually list all of them then I suggest use this:

```
using System.Reflection;

class MyClass{
    var Var1;
    var Var2;
    ...
    var infos = typeof(MyClass).GetFields();
    foreach(var info in infos)
    {
        if(info.GetValue(this)==null) ShowErrorMessage(info.Name);
    }
}
```

note: you can replace GetFields with GetMembers or GetProperties...

Answer (score 0):

Put all those variables into a list. You can then loop over them as you want to.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the "if any" semantics you are after, you could create a static class as follows (I put it in my TypeExtensions namespace)

```
public static class NotAssigned {
    public static bool AnyOf( params object[] Objects){
        foreach (var o in Objects)
            if (o == null)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage would be as follows

```
Var Var1 = blah1;
Var Var2 = blah2;
if (NotAssigned.AnyOf( blah1, blah2))
    throw new Exception
```

With a few minor logic adjustments, you can throw on an AllOff function, also perhaps an "Assigned" class, with AnyOf and AllOf.

So far I've only made use of NotAssigned.AnyOf

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `params` parameter operator to pass a list of null parameters:

```
    public static void ThrowIfNull(params object[] input)
    {
        foreach (var item in input)
        {
            //Your choice of how you want to handle this. I chose an exception.
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }
    }
```

which will allow you to:

```
    int? nullableInt = null;
    string someNullString = null;

    ThrowIfNull(nullableInt, someNullString);
```

There are also other ways you can approach this problem. For instance you can create an extension method for `IEnumerable`:

```
public static class NullExtensionMethods
{
    public static void ThrowIfHasNull<T>(this IEnumerable collection)
        where T : Exception, new()
    {
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                throw new T();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void ThrowIfHasNull(this IEnumerable collection)
    {
        ThrowIfHasNull<NullReferenceException>(collection);
    }
}
```

Making this possible:

```
 string someNullString = null;
 new string[] { someNullString }.ThrowIfHasNull();

 //or for context specific exceptions

 new string[] { someNullString }.ThrowIfHasNull<ArgumentNullException>();
```

Though I prefer to avoid exceptions where possible. You can make the following changes:

```
public static class NullExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool HasNull(this IEnumerable collection)
    {
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Allowing you to handle things much more gracefully:

```
var nullDetected = new string[] { someNullString }.HasNull();
```

Since we are using extension methods, we can further exploit the feature by adding overloads for specific cases. So for instance an empty string can be treated the same way `String.IsNullOrEmpty`. In this case I would add an extra extension method `HasNullOrEmpty`:

```
    public static bool HasNullOrEmpty(this IEnumerable<string> collection)
    {
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Though the trade of is that the type must be `IEnumerable<string>`

Answer (score 0):

This is my way, considered box and unbox object.

Even though **ref** can make more performance, but coding to pass params is ugly

Useage:

```
void Bala(Guid? id, int? type){
    if (NullableChecker.AnyIsNull(id, type)){
        //Do your stuff
    }
}
```

The class can use T4 or similar tools to generate code

```
internal static class NullableChecker
{
    public static bool AnyIsNull<T>(T? value) where T : struct
    {
        return false == value.HasValue;
    }

    public static bool AnyIsNull<T1, T2>(T1? value1, T2? value2) where T1 : struct where T2 : struct
    {
        return false == value1.HasValue || false == value2.HasValue;
    }

    public static bool AnyIsNull<T1, T2, T3>(T1? value1, T2? value2, T3? value3) where T1 : struct where T2 : struct where T3 : struct
    {
        return false == value1.HasValue || false == value2.HasValue || false == value3.HasValue;
    }

    public static bool AnyIsNull<T1, T2, T3, T4>(T1? value1, T2? value2, T3? value3, T4? value4) where T1 : struct where T2 : struct where T3 : struct where T4 : struct
    {
        return false == value1.HasValue || false == value2.HasValue || false == value3.HasValue || false == value4.HasValue;
    }
}
```